# Android views and custom orientation change, what's the best way to handle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I've an android app that has multiple views. I've disabled the automatic orientation switching by declaring `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` for my activity.

Q1) How I should re-activate views in `onConfigurationChanged()`? It seems I need to reset the content view using `setContentView` method. Is there an alternative way to signal view that now you should inflate the landscape/portrait version of the layout? Some of my views contain quite complicated `states/modeless` dialogs etc that can appear any time so deleting the view object and re-instantiating it just doesn't sound right.

Q2) What's the best way in `onConfigurationChanged()` to know which view we should actually now activate i.e. what was focused when orientation change was initiated? I'm reluctant to rely on `getCurrentFocus()` as it can be null sometimes.

Comment: have you tried with setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);   onResume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1) How I should re-activate views in onConfigurationChanged()?

As you mentioned, `setContentView()` is a good way to do this. Just remember to not always pass in a layout XML to this method. Instead, pre-inflate your layout into a `View` object and pass in that View object to setContentView. That way, you don't incur the cost of re-creating your view object on every orientation change.

The following is a sample code - may not work as-is; but meant to illustrate my point.

```
View mLandscapeView;
View myPortraitView

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    View myLandscapeView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_landscape, null);
    View myPortraitView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_portrait, null);
    //...
}

@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config){
    if(config.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //adjust mLandscapeView as needed
        setContentView(mLandscapeView);
    }

    // And so on ... 

}
```

Comment: Yeah I think that could work, I however solved this using good old MVC model. It's just apparently not smart to add too much logic to view implementation, separated most of the state management to controller side and now I don't have to care whether view is destroyed or not.

Comment: Can you please kindly guide me How you used MVC pattern to handle this orientation..

Comment: @ooxio Can you please share how you solved using MVC. Many people are looking for this solution. your solution might help us